# AngularJS jasmine service mock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

There seems to be several ways to stub out services when testing Angular controllers using Jasmine.

One of the ways I've become accustomed to is to do the following in a beforeEach block:

```
mockService = {}

inject( $controller) ->
  controller = $controller('MyController', {
    MyRealService: mockService
  })
```

Another way is to use `$provide` to stub my dependency injected service:

```
module('app', ($provide) ->
  mockService = {}
  $provide.value('MyService', mockService)
)
```

When I had:

```
afterEach ->
  httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
```

in my test. Only the `$provide` method worked, and the `$controller` style would not. Using `$controller` the test was somehow hitting `MyRealService` and including all of its dependencies, rather than ignoring and using `mockService`. Without the `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()`, both methods seem to behave the same and the test passes.

What are the main differences between the 2 styles? When should you be using one over the other? Any ideas why the effect of stubbing is different in the presence of a `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()`

Comment: Could you show us the internal implementation of MyRealService and the controller you are testing?

Comment: were you also doing:  beforeEach(module('app')); prior to your inject() in your other case?

Answer (score 0):

**What are the main differences between the two styles?**

In the first case, we inject our fake objects ourselves into the controller, whereas with the second method we tell Angular where it can find the fakes when it needs to inject them later.

**When should you be using one over the other?**

I prefer the first method as it is more obvious, and especially when we test controllers, it is sufficient.

I mostly use the `$provide` method when dealing with services/factories or routing testing. Since services can't be "newed up" like controllers, we need to trick the inject function to use our fakes using the provider.

And in the case of testing routing we have no other possibility than using the provider to stub out the services used in the route resolvers.

**Any ideas why the effect of stubbing is different in the presence of a verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()**

Not really sure on how to answer this one, but I have found `$httpBackend` to be not-so-obvious to use. Especially when testing routes. It records all traffic, including things like calls to templates defined in a route etc, which makes it very easy to overlook a call in the setup.