# Why is there a difference between these approaches in testing a controller

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

While doing a Jasmine test for an Angular Controller, I find a difference between these two approaches. There shouldn't be, but there is. That said, using debug, I find in both cases the correct mocked items are coming thru, however the tests behave differently.

First: Here we mock service items which are then injected using DI into the controller at creation.

```
$provide.value('core.data.CompanyService', companyService);
$provide.value('core.list.ListGenerator', listGeneratorFactory);
$provide.value('core.actions.ActionContext', actionContext);

ActivitiesCtrl = $controller('activities.ActivitiesCtrl', {
  $scope: scope
});
```

Second:
Here we explicitly specify the injected service items in the controller creation:

```
ActivitiesCtrl = $controller('activities.ActivitiesCtrl', {
  $scope: scope,
  'core.lists.ListGenerator': listGeneratorFactory,
  'core.actions.ActionContext': actionContext,
  'core.data.CompanyService': companyService
});
```

Comment: Define how they behave differently

Comment: Duplicates, but without answer: 1) [Angular.js testing controllers: specifying dependencies via $provide vs $controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776642/angular-js-testing-controllers-specifying-dependencies-via-provide-vs-control) 2) [AngularJS jasmine service mock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510463/angularjs-jasmine-service-mock)

Comment: @Phil I had been restructuring the application, and using the first approach made the tests fail, but the second approach made the tests pass. Yet both in theory are doing the same thing.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information such as *"how did the tests fail with the first approach"*. You should also provide actual code as your first code section above is not possible; `$provide` is only available during module *config* whereas `$controller` would only be available within an `inject` callback

Answer (score 0):

If your first snippet of code is actually what you have, then I think I see the problem; providers should be set in a module *config* section and `$controller` should be accessed within an `inject` callback.

Given proper setup of the mocks prior to this, the following are equivalent

1. Providers on the `$injector`

   ```
   beforeEach(function() {
       module('your.controller.module', function($provide) {
           $provide.value('core.list.ListGenerator', listGeneratorFactory);
           $provide.value('core.actions.ActionContext', actionContext);
           $provide.value('core.data.CompanyService', companyService);
       });

       inject(function($controller) {
           // assuming scope is defined somewhere
           ActivitiesCtrl = $controller('activities.ActivitiesCtrl', {
               $scope: scope
           });
       });
   });
   ```
2. Controller locals

   ```
   beforeEach(inject($controller) {
       // again, assuming scope is defined somewhere

       ActivitiesCtrl = $controller('activities.ActivitiesCtrl', {
           $scope: scope,
           'core.lists.ListGenerator': listGeneratorFactory,
           'core.actions.ActionContext': actionContext,
           'core.data.CompanyService': companyService
       });            
   }));
   ```